# Jquery window horizontal scroll animate with right to left direction

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, jquery-animate

I am working on project that has horizontal scroll animated with jquery and it currently works very well.

My problem is when the website translates for right to left languages, the horizontal scroll needs to move right to left.

```
$('body').animate({scrollRight:200},150);
```

The above code doesn't work. How can I animate horizontal scrolling in right to left direction

Answer (score 2):

Cant't you detect the page orientation and based on that scroll left or right?
i.e.

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp){
    var x = document.getElementById(el) || document.body;
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}

if (getStyle(null,'direction') == 'ltr'){
    $('body').animate({scrollLeft: -200},150);
} else {
    $('body').animate({scrollLeft:200},150);
}
```

PS: [jQuery scrollRight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905832/jquery-scrollright)

Comment: no . i can detect , my problem is `$('body').animate({scrollRight:200},150);` dont work for me

Comment: sorry, apparently you can you can use scrollLeft for both directions, look at the linked answer.

Comment: yes i must work with scrollLeft , scrollRight dont work at all , tnx