# Scroll a div's scroll bar all the way to the right with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

This question is a duplicate of [jQuery scrollRight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905832/jquery-scrollright)

I have a div with a lot of content (width-wise) and overflow:auto, so i have the scroll bar at the bottom.  It starts scrolled fully to the left:  is there a way to scroll it all the way over to the right, using jQuery/native JS?

Even if there's a way to do this in CSS (which would normally be preferable) i need to do it in JS, because some other stuff happens in the table first in JS (using the jquery plugin DataTables to be specific) in the dom ready block, so my code needs to run after that.

I thought this would be simple but i've not managed to google anything useful.

thanks!  max

Comment: Did you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905832/jquery-scrollright?

Comment: No, i hadn't, thanks. That works perfectly.  Sorry for the duplicate.  I'm not sure if protocol dictates that this is marked as a duplicate now or if i just delete the question?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it - you might consider it a bit hacky.

In the sample below, "#test" is a div with 100px width and overflow: auto.

```
$("#test").css("overflow","none");
$("#test").css("width","none");
var width = $("#test").width();
$("#test").css("overflow","auto");
$("#test").css("width","100px");
$("#test").animate({scrollLeft: width}, 100);
```

Here I'm getting rid of the width and overflow CSS properties to work out what the true width of the content is. Then I'm putting the CSS properties back on and scrolling to that width.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dReFh/