# jQuery Horizontal Scroll to DIV on Click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a parallax setup so the user can scroll down when they are on the landing of the site. Once they scroll down, they can then scroll across to different pages.

I have tried using the jQuery code:

```
$("#scrollTo").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#page2").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

});

I want to make it so when the user clicks the button it scrolls across or horizontally to the second page "view2". However the system does not seem to work.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qm7s60ud/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905832/jquery-scrollright
this question might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animate should be on `.wrapper` class since it is the element that has an overflow.

```
.wrapper { 
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: auto; //overflow that causes the div to have scroll bar
}
```

And instead of `scrollTop` and `.offset().top`, (*Because this is for Vertical*)

**It should be** `scrollLeft` and `.offset().left` .. (*This is for Horizontal*)

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/qm7s60ud/4/)

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
var top_value=$("#page2").position().top
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '+='+top_value},2000);
```

We get top pixel value of div page2 in variable top_value and scroll down to that pixel