# function that needs to scroll right rather then left

Tags: javascript, function, scroll

can someone please have a look at this javaScript and tell me what i have to change to make it scroll right. Thanks

```
   $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('body').animate({
              scrollLeft: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

added the HTML:

```
     <div class = "option1"> 
    <a href= #point1> ➟
    </a>
   </div>

<div class = "cheet">
<img src = "https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/108/posts/21424/image/run-animation-2-3-clipping-mask-base.gif">
</div>
    <div class = "page2">
        <div class = "land4">

        <img src =   "http://www.mcdonalds.com/us_assets/value_all_assets/GOC_TreeSilhouettes.png"> 
        </div>

          </div>
```

Comment: Probably need `scrollLeft: -target.offset().top;` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905832/jquery-scrollright

Comment: yea just tried doesn't seem to work still moves left if i add the "-"

Comment: Could you add your html to the question so we can play with it too?

Answer (score 1):

If you put `scrollleft` as a negative number, it will scroll right.

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollLeft: -target.offset().top
}, 1000);
```

I added [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidgourde/chn7kgwn/) as an example.

I also found a JSFiddle that does what you want with pictures, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6HwL/7/).

Comment: I added two JSFiddles, you should find more details here. And they work. Unless I did not understand what you wanted to do.

Comment: thanks yea had a look at them, looks good - I'll have a tinker. Thankyou

Comment: @sosro: Mark this answer as correct answer. As, the user has helped you.