# How to scroll left on load in overflowed div to specific class name?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

How to scroll left to element that has class `pincard-checked`, Below is what I have tried to no effect. Thank you for any help.

HTML:

```
<div class="pinGridWrapper">
<div class="pinGrid">


<div class="pin"> content </div>
<div class="pin"> content </div>
<div class="pin pincard-checked"> content </div>
<div class="pin"> content </div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pinGridWrapper {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pinGrid {
display:inline-flex;
list-style: none;
padding:0px;
}

.pin {
width:300px;
background: #fff;
margin:0px 10px 0px 10px; 
position: relative;
height:525px; 
margin-top:10px;
display:inline-block;
 overflow-y:hidden;
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.pinGridWrapper').animate({scrollLeft: $('.pincard-checked').offset().left}, 800);
      return false;
   });
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hzeLekht/2/)

UPDATE: I think the issue is with using inline-flex on pinGrid. Just in case anyone has come across this before.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this was the way of doing it.

For anyone who may need to do this in the future, make sure the scroll script is loaded after the page has been, otherwise nothing will happen.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.pinGridWrapper').animate({
            scrollLeft: $('.pincard-checked').offset().left
        }, 1000, function() {
        });
    });
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hzeLekht/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this
check https://jsfiddle.net/hzeLekht/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.pincard-checked').offset().top
    }, 800, function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: I have added fiddle

Comment: yes, thats with a vertically overflowed div, mine is horizontal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905832/jquery-scrollright
refer this

Comment: Thanks, but that is scrolling by px amount, not to specific element.