# How to horizontal scroll datatable on click event?

Tags: jquery, datatables, horizontal-scrolling

I've set up a datatable with a large number of columns. Currently there is a bottom scrollbar but I want to link a scroll right to a button at the top of the datatable.

The button is linked to a click event and I found this jQuery example to animate a [horizontal scroll right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905832/jquery-scrollright). But when I click the button the table isn't scrolled horizontally right:

```
        $("#scrollXRight-btn").click(function () {

            //$('div.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollRight($('#escalation').scrollRight() + 20); //method 1 didn't work

            var leftPos = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft();
            $("div.dataTables_scrollBody").animate({ scrollLeft: leftPos + 200 }, 800);

        });
```

I did try using the selector [mentioned here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11383/expose-scroll-event) but the animation didn't fire.

ID of datatable: `escalation`

Class of datatable container: `dataTables_wrapper no-footer`

**Question:**

How can you horizontal scroll a datatable on click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable [scrollX](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX) in datatables and maybe use [fixed columns extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/), if needed.