# Opening a new window scrolled to extreme right

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which opens a small window. I'm trying to scroll the window to the right once loaded. I have tried scrollLeft property but I guess the problem is the code runs in the active window and not the popup.

```
let smallInterval = setInterval(()=>{

    let emailAddress = document.querySelector("body > workspace-layout > workspace")
    ?.shadowRoot.querySelector("input");
    if(emailAddress !== undefined && emailAddress !== null){
      
        let obj = {
        email: emailAddress.value,
        };
        console.log(obj.email);

        const MyUrl ="https://test.com"

        let newWindow2 = window.open(MyUrl , "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=50,left=3000,width=50,height=200");

        clearInterval(smallInterval);
    }else{
    }

},1000);
```

Comment: _“ have tried scrollright property”_ - what are you talking about? Where would any `scrollright` property exist? The property to determine scroll position on the x axis is `scrollLeft`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8906007/1427878

Comment: that was a typo.. I updated the question.

Comment: Still don’t see what you actually tried with it. _Show_ what you are talking about, instead of _just_ talking about it.

Comment: Never mind.. I will figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **window.outerWidth** property.
If window is small than 150px in width you'll have to tune the diff offset.

```
window.open(MyUrl, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=50,left=" + (window.outerWidth - 150) + ",width=150,height=200")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newWindow.onload = function() {
newWindow.scrollTo(800,500);
};
```

I got it to work. Hope this helps someone in future.